# Nautilus Elementary, no Edit / Preferences?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus-elementary

I installed Nautilus Elementary 2.32.2.1from the PPA and I don't have "Edit / Preferences" in Nautilus.

Does anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

(assuming this picture is not yours:)

The image you have in your post you can access by hitting F8 in Nautilus. This will add a cogwheel to the topright. Click it to get to the screen in your question. See here:

[image]

After installing you also need to restart nautilus with
`nautilus -q`

Comment: I added that screenshot. I'm not sure if Aaron means he can't see the menu bar, which would be fixed by your post, or that he doesn't have preferences at all.

Comment: The screenshots aren't mine. Someone else added those. I saw this answer in another forum somewhere; **I had to add the PPA and run dist-upgrade a 2nd time for everything to work properly. The first time there was no "preferences" or the cog, F8 didn't do anything, and those 3 buttons on the top right weren't there. Very strange, but it's working now.**

Answer (score 0):

You mean that isn't your screenshot?

Hitting F8 will toggle the Menubar. Then you will have Access to File, Edit, View, Go, etc

Answer (score 0):

Double check that Nautilus 2.32.2 REALLY is installed. I had the same problem in Maverick. I installed Nautilus-elementary via PPA and it didn't upgrade after the upgrading process. So I solved it with a simple command:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```